# Rails Automatically Generate Password with has_secure_password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to automatically generate a password for a `User` when using `has_secure_password` in a Rails 4.0 app (note: that's why there's no `attr_accessor`).

I have a very simple `User` model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password
  validates :email, presence: true
end
```

I'm wondering how I can create a password using `SecureRandom.hex(8)` in a `before_save` call. I tried adding `before_save { self.password = SecureRandom.hex(8) }` and various versions of that, but when I tried to save it in the Rails console, it said the `password` was empty.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `before_validation` callback instead. `before_save` runs after `validate` and so your record will be always invalid.

Also consider checking if there is a password set already. Otherwise you may set a new one every time the record is changed.

Find more information about the [ActiveRecord callback chain here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html).

Answer (score 0):

Callbacks are a useful solution but make testing difficult as you're adding required layers of complexity.

Another approach would be creating a class that sits "above" users.  I wouldn't argue that this is the best solution, but it's one I've found useful.  Note that this class inherits from the `User` class:

```
# user_with_default_password.rb
class UserWithDefaultPassword < User
  def initialize(options = {})
    random_password = SecureRandom.hex(8)

    options[:password] = random_password

    # If creating a user with confirmation requirements
    options[:password_confirmation] = random_password

    # Call User.new(options)
    super(options)
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
user = UserWithDefaultPassword.new() # => user.password = "ajfladfjkf..."
```

The beauty of this is that you can test User and UserWithDefaultPassword without forcing callbacks that often slow down tests.

Also, you can create users with or without default passwords if you want simply by using `User.new()` instead of `UserWithDefaultPassword.new()`.  It provides greater flexibility and better testing.

Update: 2014-04-21

Also, I recommend extracting the code for creating random password, etc... into a separate class that you can test quickly (without loading the Rails framework).  Below is a class I recently made to perform some of these simple tasks.

```
#==================================================
# Generates random/unique strings/tokens/IDs
# See: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/SecureRandom.html
# See: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out#sec-signin_success
#==================================================
class Generator
  require "securerandom"

  # General-purpose encryption using SHA1 instead of bcrypt; faster but LESS SECURE than bcrypt
  # (do not use for extremely sensitive data such as passwords)
  def self.encrypt(value)
    if value.nil? || value.empty?
      ""
    else
      Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(value.to_s)
    end
  end

  # Although a UUID would work as an auto-generated password,
  # it just seems more appropriate to make the password a random
  # string.
  def self.random_password
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(32)
  end

  # Used as a random, unique token
  def self.uuid
    SecureRandom.uuid
  end

  # Returns random number as string for admin 2-step authentication
  def self.verification_code(length)
    value = ""

    if length.nil? || length.zero?
      length = 6
    elsif length > 20
      length = 20
    end

    length.times do |num|
      value += SecureRandom.random_number(10).to_s
    end

    value
  end
end
```

Usage: `Generator.random_password # => "abc123..."`

Big benefit is you can test creation of random passwords without loading the Rails framework, which saves that 3-4 second load time.  This is (mostly) resolved with Rails 4.1 which uses Spring to pre-load your app for tests, but if you're not on Rails 4.1 (or using Spring gem) this is a better solution.